# user friendly way to create xml files from .xsd files *no coding for the user*

Tags: xml, xsd, metadata

I'm not really sure how to explain this question but I'll do my best to make it clear. I am currently writing an .xsd in order to create a metadata file for datasets. When I try to use it to map in excel it comes up with errors that only disappear if I set out the form in a really messy and not user friendly way. I was just wondering if the there was a user-friendly way for others to be able to generate xml metadata files from my schema? The people using it will not have much coding experience and it will be used on lots of different datasets.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="Data-set">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name= "DataUniqueIdentifier"/>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ProjectInformation">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="ProjectName"/>
                            <xsd:element name="ProjectCode"/>
                            <xsd:element name="ProjectLead"/>
                            <xsd:element minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="unbounded" name ="ProjectSponsors"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Authors">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="LastName"/>
                            <xsd:element name="FirstName"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Email"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Affiliation"/>
                            <xsd:element name="Role"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DataInformation">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="DatasetTitle"/>
                            <xsd:element name="StudyStartDate" type="xsd:date"/>
                            <xsd:element name="StudyEndDate" type="xsd:date"/>
                            <xsd:element name="EstimatedStudyCompletionDate" type="xsd:date"/>
                            <xsd:element name="PublicationDate" type="xsd:date"/>
                            <xsd:element name="DataLocation" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="5" name ="Keywords"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>  
                <xsd:element name= "DataUsageRights" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DataAbstract">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="unbounded" name ="InstrumentsUsed"/>
                            <xsd:element minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="unbounded" name ="AquisitionMethods"/>
                            <xsd:element minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="unbounded" name ="ProcessingMethods"/>
                            <xsd:element minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="unbounded" name ="SoftwareUsed"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DataDescription">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name ="Completion"/>
                            <xsd:element name ="ObservationCount"/>
                            <xsd:element name ="VariableCount"/>
                            <xsd:element name ="NACount"/>
                            <xsd:element name ="DatasetState"/>
                            <xsd:element minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="unbounded" name ="AnalysisPerformed"/>
                            <xsd:element minOccurs ="0" maxOccurs ="unbounded" name ="PapersPublished"> #ISSUE
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name ="PaperTitle"/> #ISSUE
                                        <xsd:element name ="URL"/> #ISSUE
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="DataDescriptors">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name ="VariableName"/>
                            <xsd:element name ="DataType"/>
                            <xsd:element name ="VariableDescription"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DataFileInformation">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name ="FileFormat"/>
                            <xsd:element name ="FileSize"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>  
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I hope I explained it well enough, any sort of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very open and doesn't seem to have a lot of details attached to it. Therefore, it will be tricky answering this in a way that will be suitable to you.

If I understand your question correctly you're talking about a situation where you have an XML schema (XSD) and you want to "generate" an XML file based on this schema without any coding.

What comes to mind are GUI based editors such as [OxygenXML](https://www.oxygenxml.com/) which allow to load an XSD and then provide auto-completion, "grid views" and other tools to make it easy/easier to write an XML base don the XSD. Furthermore, XSD validation is built right into the editor too.
There are alternatives to OxygenXML available which you will find easily searching the web for things such as *XML Editor*, *XML Development*, *XML IDE* and similar.

If this answer doesn't help you I'd recommend you adding more information to your questions.

Comment: Hi Joel, thank you for the reply. I knew it would be a tough one to answer as I struggled to word it. This is along the lines of what I am looking for. I'm fine with setting up the coding it just needs to be neat and easy to use for the end-user as they will have little to no coding experience. I will look into these options and get back to you.

Answer (score -1):

Oxygen has a tool to generate an instance document from a schema. With a little tweaking of options I generated this instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/test.xsd">
   <DataUniqueIdentifier>
   </DataUniqueIdentifier>
   <ProjectInformation>
      <ProjectName>
      </ProjectName>
      <ProjectCode>
      </ProjectCode>
      <ProjectLead>
      </ProjectLead>
      <ProjectSponsors>
      </ProjectSponsors>
      <ProjectSponsors>
      </ProjectSponsors>
   </ProjectInformation>
   <Authors>
      <LastName>
      </LastName>
      <FirstName>
      </FirstName>
      <Email>
      </Email>
      <Affiliation>
      </Affiliation>
      <Role>
      </Role>
   </Authors>
   <Authors>
      <LastName>
      </LastName>
      <FirstName>
      </FirstName>
      <Email>
      </Email>
      <Affiliation>
      </Affiliation>
      <Role>
      </Role>
   </Authors>
   <DataInformation>
      <DatasetTitle>
      </DatasetTitle>
      <StudyStartDate>2006-05-04</StudyStartDate>
      <StudyEndDate>2006-05-04</StudyEndDate>
      <EstimatedStudyCompletionDate>2006-05-04</EstimatedStudyCompletionDate>
      <PublicationDate>2006-05-04</PublicationDate>
      <DataLocation>DataLocation0</DataLocation>
      <Keywords>
      </Keywords>
      <Keywords>
      </Keywords>
   </DataInformation>
   <DataUsageRights>DataUsageRights0</DataUsageRights>
   <DataAbstract>
      <InstrumentsUsed>
      </InstrumentsUsed>
      <InstrumentsUsed>
      </InstrumentsUsed>
      <AquisitionMethods>
      </AquisitionMethods>
      <AquisitionMethods>
      </AquisitionMethods>
      <ProcessingMethods>
      </ProcessingMethods>
      <ProcessingMethods>
      </ProcessingMethods>
      <SoftwareUsed>
      </SoftwareUsed>
      <SoftwareUsed>
      </SoftwareUsed>
   </DataAbstract>
   <DataDescription>
      <Completion>
      </Completion>
      <ObservationCount>
      </ObservationCount>
      <VariableCount>
      </VariableCount>
      <NACount>
      </NACount>
      <DatasetState>
      </DatasetState>
      <AnalysisPerformed>
      </AnalysisPerformed>
      <AnalysisPerformed>
      </AnalysisPerformed>
      <PapersPublished>
         <PaperTitle>
         </PaperTitle>
         <URL>
         </URL>
      </PapersPublished>
      <PapersPublished>
         <PaperTitle>
         </PaperTitle>
         <URL>
         </URL>
      </PapersPublished>
   </DataDescription>
   <DataDescriptors>
      <VariableName>
      </VariableName>
      <DataType>
      </DataType>
      <VariableDescription>
      </VariableDescription>
   </DataDescriptors>
   <DataDescriptors>
      <VariableName>
      </VariableName>
      <DataType>
      </DataType>
      <VariableDescription>
      </VariableDescription>
   </DataDescriptors>
   <DataFileInformation>
      <FileFormat>
      </FileFormat>
      <FileSize>
      </FileSize>
   </DataFileInformation>
</Data-set>
```

which users might find helpful as a template for editing. Is that what you had in mind?

Of course you could modify the template, for example adding comments that indicate what the fields mean.

But really, you want to design a form (perhaps using XForms) that allows users to enter the data without seeing any angle brackets.